# Can't use SQL lag sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, lag

My query is like this

```
SELECT
    [day], [time],AvaliableTimes,
    CASE
       WHEN AvaliableTimes > 0 
          THEN SUM(AvaliableTimes) OVER (ORDER BY [day], [time], AvaliableTimes)
          ELSE 0 
    END AS SumValue
FROM
    [AvailableTimes] 
WHERE
    [day] = 1 AND BranchAreaId = 1
ORDER BY
    [day], [time], AvaliableTimes
```

I want to start sum from 0 if value is null or 0.

Results:

[image: Attached Image below]

Comment: What is the problem?    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a recursive CTE to do it. Perform the cumulative sum in the rcte and if AvailableTimes = 0, reset it

```
; with
cte as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (order by time)
    from    yourtable   
),
rcte as
(
    select  *, sumvalues = AvailableTimes
    from    cte
    where   rn = 1

    union all

    select  c.*, sumvalues = case when  c.AvailableTimes <> 0
                      then  r.sumvalues + c.AvailableTimes
                      else  c.AvailableTimes
                      end
    from    cte c
        inner join rcte r   on  c.rn    = r.rn + 1
)
select  day, time, AvailableTimes, sumvalues
from    rcte
order by time
```